# Run a subquery to decide whether to skip outer query, don't send parameters if skipped?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, subquery, query-string

I have the following query which is being used in Java JDBC

```
INSERT INTO account_photos (token, image, image_id, order_count) SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 from account_photos where image_id = ?)
```

It looks like it is causing a very high server load and bandwidth usage as it gets the `image` even if `image_id` is in the table.

Is there anyway to not to get the image if the NOT EXISTS is not true?

Comment: "*It looks like it is causing a very high server load*" - how do you know? Did you check the execution plan? Postgres will not retrieve the image in the sub-select statement, so why do you think it does that?

Comment: Is the problem with network usage between the java process and the db? Or just on the db itself while executing the query? If the latter, is there an index on image_id?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name is there anyway to check which query us causing the high load on postgres?

Comment: Do the operation in two phases - first insert a row without the image (NULL or empty file), then check a rowcount returned by executeUpdate to see if the record were inserted, and if yes, then perform an update of the inserted record sending the right image file. And do the commit in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this query, the image data will be transferred to the server *before the query starts*. Query processing happens in phases:

- Parse: Read the query text from the client, validate its syntax and turn it into an internal structure that describes the query
- Bind: Read the query *parameters* from the client and match them up to placeholders in the parsed query
- Execute: Actually run the query

The `IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT ...)` happens in the execute phase. The bind phase has already finished, and it's the bind phase where the image data is transferred across the network to be stored temporarily in the database server's memory.

You cannot make PostgreSQL run part of the query before binding parameters. PostgreSQL does not support lazy parameter binding, where it calls back to the client to ask for parameter data only when the query needs it. There's nothing fundamentally impossible about that, it's just not supported by the current PostgreSQL protocol, client drivers, or database server.

Thus, you have to do this in two phases, as two separate queries. Check if the image exists, and only if it does not exist, insert it.

**Note**: Your query can try to insert the image twice because two concurrent queries can both return `false` for `not exists (select...)`, and thus can both proceed to `insert`.